# How to separate multiple ajax success into two divs

Tags: php, ajax, html-table

I have an ajax script like below:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"process1.php",
        data:params,
        cache :false,
        async :false,
        success : function(res,data) {
              $("#qtycheck").html(res);
              $("#rangecheck").html(data);
              return this;
              }
        });

<div id="qtycheck"></div>
<div id="rangecheck"></div>
```

I want to separate `res,data` into two divs. But I get wrong result. for ex. we have:

```
res : 50     // inside table 1
data : 1 - 100  // inside table 2
```

correct result :

```
<div id="qtycheck">
  <table> ...50...</table>
</div>
<div id="rangecheck">
   <table> ...1 - 100..</table>
</div>
```

actual :

```
<div id="qtycheck">
<table> ...50...</table>
<table> ...1 - 100..</table>
</div>
<div id="rangecheck"> success </div>
```

---

UPDATE

to make clear where is table come from, this the query :

```
$sql= "SELECT .......";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($res);

echo "<table id ='appear2' border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse;font: 16px/20px Calibri, 
                Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color:white; ' width='auto'>";
        echo "<tr id='tblhead' style='text-align:center;'>";
        for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
        {
                $field = mysql_fetch_field($res);
                echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
        {
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach($row as $cell)
                echo "<td>$cell</td>";
                echo "</tr>\n";
        }

$sql= "SELECT .......";
$data=mysql_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($data);

echo "<table id ='appear2' border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse;font: 16px/20px Calibri, 
                Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color:white; ' width='auto'>";
        echo "<tr id='tblhead' style='text-align:center;'>";
        for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
        {
                $field = mysql_fetch_field($data);
                echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($data))
        {
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach($row as $cell)
                echo "<td>$cell</td>";
                echo "</tr>\n";
        }
```

After this ajax will get parameter res and data. all table can show,but the result is both of table show inside one div.

Comment: this may be because server side return value.Are u returning your result as array?

Comment: Did you print your data and res variable? what value both of them contains? please check it first.

Comment: @all see my updated post.actually result show inside table.i try to separate table into two divs. but both of table just show in one id.

Answer (score 0):

ajax success function passed three parameters:

```
Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
```

The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object

the result of your ajax request will be one string like:`<table>...50...</table><table>...1-100...</table>` as you see.

So I suggest you to send two ajax request to get the data. 
If you must do that, you can do it like this:

```
$("#qtycheck").html(res.substring(0, res.indexOf("<table>",1)));
$("#rangecheck").html(res.substring(res.indexOf("<table>",1)));
```

But it is not a good way. Two ajax request is better

Comment: res and data is come from different query.

Comment: what is from different query mean? I think the response from server is in one string(which is the first parameter in function).

Comment: I can not understand where is <table></table> from. But I think you can use data.split("\n"); to separate "50" and "1-100". Then you can show them in different div

Comment: Updated, hope it can help you